# unordered_map adding returns to strings read in from a file c++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a text file, formatted:

```
"stringx, stringy"
"stringx, stringy"
```

e.t.c.

I have put my code below to show how I'm reading into my unordered map, parsing the text and making stringx the key with stringy the value.

For the problem I am trying to solve I need to also have another map, in the reverse order i.e key being stringy, and value being stringx.

The values are getting entered correctly, when i output straightData, you see

```
"stringx:stringy"
```

but when i output reverseData, it's instead

```
"stringy
 :stringx"
```

I don't know if this is an issue for the overall scope of my program (i need to get one key, append it to a list, and then take the value from the key and use that to lookup another key/value pair). 
I'm just thinking however, if it automatically has a newline in the data, would

```
stringx
```

be the same as

```
(space)
stringx
```

?

I don't know if i'm even making sense, but as always all help would be massively appreciated!

```
typedef unordered_map<string, string> mymap;

int main()
{
mymap map1;
mymap map2; 
list <pair<string, string>> list1; 
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("values.txt");
string forParse;
string first, second;
while (getline(myFile, forParse))
{
    stringstream x(forParse);
    getline(x, first, ',');
    getline(x, second);
    map1[first] = second; 
    map2[second] = first;  
}

for (auto& x: map2) cout << x.first << ":" << x.second << endl;
```

Comment: Is there actually a line break when you output the 'reverse map' or is it just an extra space? (By the way, I'm removing the unordered-map tag, even though you use one, your problem is unrelated to it.)

Comment: It looks like you have a trailing newline at the end of "stringy".

Comment: yeah theres a line break, not an extra space, but the issue is the text file i'm using is very long and has been given to me for processing, so i can't go changing it, anyway around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading files into an std::unordered\_map c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589026/reading-files-into-an-stdunordered-map-c)

Comment: @KerrekSB it's more of a new issue that has arisen, i can delete the old post if you want?

Comment: @aspiring_programmer: Sure, that's an option, too.

Comment: is there any way i can get around this issue? is it even an issue when doing element lookup?

Comment: anyone? this is causing me a right headache :|

Comment: Can you inspect directly char code of map2.first? It end in '\n' code=10 or something other, like '\r' code=13 ??